# WordPress: How to programmatically sort the posts by the title?

Tags: wordpress

In a page on a complex WordPress site, I need to sort the image icons by the tile of the post the image link leads. Is there a way to get this done in the new WP_Query() below?

```
$corepage = get_field('purposeful_purveyor_settings', 'option');
$purveyor_ppp = $corepage['purposeful_purveyor_posts_per_page'];
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$data= new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'=>'purposeful_purveyor',
'posts_per_page' => $purveyor_ppp,
'paged' => $paged,
));

  <?php if($data->have_posts()): while($data->have_posts()): $data->the_post(); ?>

  <div class="col col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
    <?php get_template_part('template-parts/purveyor/purveyor--entry'); ?>
  </div>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Check WP_Query [order and orderby](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. It worked. Please turn your comment an answer so I will accept it and it will someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the order and orderby properties.

Check WP_Query [order and orderby](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)